# Domain and Range contradiction?

Tags: inverse-function

> $$y = \log(1 +(k - 1)^2)$$
>
> The domain is all reals and the range is $y \geq 0.$

First, the inverse. Swapping the variables:

$k = \log(1 + (y - 1)^2)\\e^k = 1 + (y - 1)^2\\e^k - 1 = (y - 1)^2\\y = (e^k - 1)^{1/2} + 1$

This inverse has the restriction $x \geq 1.$

But this doesn't match the range of the original function. The range of this inverse function doesn't match the domain (all reals) of the original function either.

**Why is this occurring? Don't inverse functions swap the domain for the range, and the range for the domain?**

---

**EDIT**

To make the function invertible, we shall restrict the domain to $k \geq 1.$ This function now has an inverse.

Answer (score 2):

[Your original function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20%3D%20log%281%2B%28x-1%29%5E2%29) $\ y = \log(1+(x-1)^2)\ $ is many-to-one, as $\ f(x-1) = f(-(x-1)).$

However, you're only allowed to find the inverse of a [one-to-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) function.

$$$$

You could do this by restricting the domain of the original function to $\ x\geq 1,\ $ in which case the original function will also have range of $\ y\geq 0.$ Then, since this function is one-to-one, we can find the inverse function of it. In fact, it will be the same as what you found in your working, so the inverse function is:

$y = (e^x - 1)^{1/2} + 1,\ $ with domain $\ x\geq 0,\ $ and range $\ y\geq 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Your final line ought to be $$y = \pm(e^k - 1)^{1/2} + 1.\tag#$$

[Its graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dbjym3eotb) fails the [horizontal-line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test), so $(\#)$ doesn't represent a function, so the original function actually has no inverse.

---

**EDIT**

After you restrict the given function (good idea!), its domain and range indeed becomes its inverse function's range and domain, respectively, as expected. Then there is no longer any issue/contradiction, right?

Comment: The original domain has to be restricted. I've restricted it to be k >= 1. That function has an inverse. However, the domain and range for the inverses don't seem interchangeable.

Comment: @John Please use mathjax (enclose symbols within dollar signs), and please refrain from making edits that render existing Answers incoherent.

Comment: I believe I answered my own question, yes. I've been looking at the problem for too long and even though I restricted the domain, I continued to compare the inverse to the original function (with the unrestricted domain). It may still help others, though.